# What is an Alicorn?

Tags: kittens-game

All I know about Alicorns is that they require the Sky Palace.

I know what a Unicorn is. I know a little about what its role in the game is (to date). But I don't really know anything about Alicorns. Are Alicorns animals, like Unicorns? But what is an Alicorn (in Kittens game)?

I checked on the wiki and there a search for "alicorn" yields nothing. I checked with google and it seems like "alicorn" can be used to mean just the horn, a unicorn with no horn, or a unicorn with wings. Could someone please explain what the role of Alicorns are in Kittens game?

Comment: Text-based games can use any arbitrary string to represent something without any thought at all to what it "is".

Comment: Where are you seeing you need Alicorns?  I'm not seeing anything about them.

Comment: @StrixVaria Be that as it may, if it is a horn, then it is a resource. If it is a flying unicorn, then it could be a kind of soldier. If it is a unicorn without a horn, then how did that happen? I think it's useful enough to know.

Comment: @GlenWheeler There might not be any sort of reasoning.

Comment: @GlenWheeler It seems like the only real mechanical question here is what use there is for alicorns. Anything about the non-existent "mythology" of such creatures is fluff. Would you mind editing your question to be more focused?

Comment: @Frank It's mentioned in the list of Achievements.

Comment: @StrixVaria Is that better?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Kittens game Alicorns are winged unicorns from the Unicorn dimension that are capable of controlling time.

You can banish them to the Crimsonmoon, a sattelite of Cath, to gather their magical chronomancy energy in a form of Time Crystals

Comment: Answer from the developer!

Answer (score 7):

An Alicorn is exactly that -- a winged unicorn.

I can cite both [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alicorn) (Etymology 2) and the [My Little Pony Wikia](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Alicorns).

I leave it as an excercise to the reader as to which is the more trustworthy source!

As to the game itself -- they are simply another resource you can obtain, like any other number of creatures and/or materials. [Billy Mailman's answer here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/184886/336) goes into the nitty-gritty of Unicorns and Alicorns, but the bottom line is that presently, you can acquire them (and sacrifice them for Time Crystals), but they aren't good for much else.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the game's description of the Sky Palace makes it pretty clear that it can't be using Wikitionary's first definition. And in my opinion, this doesn't really answer the question. The only useful information about their "role" in the game  would be what benefit they provide exactly, or that they don't provide any benefit.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Currently, they do not.

Comment: Every resource eventually gets to the point that it cannot be exchanged for anything else. It is useful to know that these can be exchanged for Time Crystals, even though that is not *really* useful for anything yet.