# How do you attract the rarest religion resource? (spoilers!)

Tags: kittens-game

I'm trying for a total completionist run, slightly editor-assisted (I keep a separate "testing" save from my main, legit save).  Long story short, I have more than seventy Sky Palaces, but I still haven't gotten a single

> alicorn.

What am I missing?  How do I get this rare resource so that I can finish out my technology tree?

Comment: read [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/184886/69152) answer, especially the last section.

Comment: @Damek yeah, they're just not coming.  I wasn't sure if how to get them had changed.  I've got over 100 Palaces now, still nothing.  Thanks.  It's funny I got linked to an answer I edited once :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chance of an Alicorn is a mere 2 in 100000 per palace per day. Even a hundred Sky Palaces still leave you with a one in a thousand chance of getting an alicorn each day.

That said, if you've been waiting for a long time, and are thoroughly convinced that something's wrong, you may want to save, and then refresh the page; this tends to fix up any minor bugs that can sometimes stop the random events from occurring correctly.

Comment: Just to clarify before I accept - is that per in-game day or per real day?

Comment: It's per in-game day.

Comment: Yeah, it's been years in game since I got 50000 Sky Palaces (this run is no longer *slightly* editor-assisted, more like *heavily*), still none.  Save-export-refresh time, thanks ^_^

Comment: One sky palace gives an average of about one alicorn per real day.  If you build seventy sky palaces and run it overnight, you should have quite a few alicorns.

Comment: @Brilliand I did (I was around 84 palaces when I went to bed), I'm guessing I've just bugged them with the editor-assisted run.  I'm just trying to figure out where "100% completion" is since the new stuff has been added before I try to do it on my legit save... :P

Comment: @gatherer, yeah, if you're editing your save, there's some internal caching of certain resource amounts/rates/chances for things that might not be updated.